# iPhone Sound: Adjust speed of playback of audio file while playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

is there a way to adjust the speed of the playback of an audio while playing in Objective C for the iPhone/iPod touch?

Also would be interesting if playing a file backwards would be possible.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 6):

`AVAudioPlayer` doesn't give you speed control, but it does let you set the position, so you could do a poor man's speed up/reverse the same way QuickTime Player does: by jumping through the file and playing small snippets at normal speed.

Or you decompress the samples yourself with an offline `AudioQueue` and do whatever rate you want. That's what I do.

Comment: Hi Rhythmic Fistman,

thanks for your reply! Could you send me an email to tom@kiesl.eu I like to ask you a question...

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Why not ask it as a question on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5):

A cheesy way to do it is to tweak the sample rate when you send it to the playback engine (Audio Queue, Remote I/O Unit, OpenAL).  For PCM -- and I'm not sure this would work for anything other than PCM (so you'd have to decompress an MP3 or AAC with Audio Converter Services first) -- you could speed up your audio by adjusting the AudioStreamBasicDescription like this:

```
audioStreamDesc.mSampleRate = audioStreamDesc.mSampleRate * 1.2;
```

Note that this also changes the pitch of your audio: not only is it faster, it's also higher pitched.  The Mac has a system-supplied audio unit that allows you to change playback speed without changing pitch, but it seems to be absent on iPhone.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your reply. Yes I did this and this is working fine, but I am not able to change the speed while playing. Or can I? And playing backwards is also not possible, or is it?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I don't think Audio Converters work with MP3/AAC on the iPhone. Unless it's been fixed in 3.0, you have to use an offline Audio Queue.

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 6 (and I believe 5) you can adjust playback rate within AVAudioPlayer; no extra code necessary:

```
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
    player.enableRate=YES;
    player.rate = 0.5;
    [player play];
```

Rate can range between .5 and 2.0, and can be adjusted during playback as long as enableRate is set to YES before playback starts.