# Would this code work for itunes' purchased AAC format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, audio

I'm making an iphone app that needs to adjust audio speed, and in [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191313/iphone-sound-adjust-speed-of-playback-of-audio-file-while-playing) , it decompresses audio, so I'm concerned with it working for Itunes' Encoded/Purchased AAC Audio format. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but it should work.  iTunes music isn't copy-protected anymore, it's just tagged with the customer's name.

Comment: Correction: New purchases aren't playback-protected (they're just normal .m4a file), but existing .m4p files still have DRM intact and still require proper authorization.

Comment: So, would DRM protected files run with this code? I know that current iTunes music will, but what about previously purchased music?